# Создание EditText с закруглёнными углами без нижней линии

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Как создать EditText вот такого вида : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1.Создать закруглённые углы?

2.Что бы не было нижней линии ?

Comment: А что здесь "кастомного"? И из картинки совершенно не ясно что это - просто картинка, обычный TextView, WebView или что-то другое. Раскройте детали.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на картинке - MultiLine EditText . А каким образом можно ещё сделать такой EditText не используя?

Comment: Я не вижу здесь EditText. Я вижу TextView с нестандартным шрифтом и белым фоном с закруглёнными углами..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как мне доказать Вам что это EditText ?? :D

Comment: Доказывать не надо, я готов на слово поверить) Просто совершенно не ясно в чём у вас проблема. Что из того, что на картинке отличается от  стандартного вида? Т.е. что вам таки непонятно как сделать? И что будет, если заменить `EditText` в вашем вопросе на `TextView` - что изменится? Мне кажется, что то, что это таки  `EditText` никак не относится к сути дела.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 1.Создать закруглённые углы .  2. Что бы не было нижней линии .

Comment: Напишите это в заголовок вопроса и в сам вопрос - отвечу)

Comment: Надо в заголовок ещё

Comment: А что именно в заголовок написать?

Comment: Про белый фон и скруглённые углы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно `en-SO` надо [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16161493/3212712):

1. Создаём фон в `res/drawable`

Файл `bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

2.Устанавливаем его как фон любой вьюхе:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

---

Ответ находится по ключевикам [android background corner white](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=-IVvWqf9G8G-sAHM7oiYDQ&q=android%20background%20corner%20white&oq=android%20background%20corner%20%D1%86%D1%80&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i160k1.243107.246082.0.247133.8.7.1.0.0.0.140.630.5j2.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.471...33i21k1.0.C_HBa7XGzYk)